# Some basic concepts of Carnot engine

Tags: thermodynamics

In a Carnot engine, when gas expands adiabatically then why does it fall to a particular temperature? And then why must the lower reservoir's temperature be equal to the temperature of the gas?

Comment: I am new to thermodynamics so if above question is wrong please help me correcting my concepts about heat engines .

Comment: How much do you know about the conditions governing adiabatic expansion, specifically, the equations that must be satisfied and the heat gained or lost? Thinking about those things, found in any introductory physics or intermediate thermo text, will answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

As you may already know, a Carnot engine is the most efficient heat engine possible (though it cannot be $100\%$ efficient due to the Third Law of Thermodynamics). You can see a diagram of the Carnot cycle below:

[image: The Carnot cycle]

## General overview of the stages in the Carnot Cycle:

The first stage in the Carnot cycle is **Isothermal expansion**. During this stage, the volume of the gas increases as the pressure decreases. The temperature inside the engine is constant, so the pressure and volume before and after this stage can be calculated using Boyle's Law (assuming the working substance in the heat engine is an ideal gas). At this stage, heat goes into the system.

During the second stage, there is **Adiabatic expansion**. During this stage, there is no change in thermal energy, so no heat will enter or exit the system. The volume of the gas will increase but the pressure and temperature of the gas will decrease. The temperature is not lost to the surroundings (since no heat is allowed to escape) instead, it is used to expand the gas.

For the next two stages, the reverse process occurs. There is isothermal compression followed by adiabatic compression. Overall, the work done is positive.

## A more complex way to show the decrease in temperature is as follows:

From the law of conservation of energy, we know that: $$Q = W + ∂U \\ Q= \text{thermal energy, is zero in the adiabatic process},\\W = \text{the work done, it is positive since the volume is increasing},\\ ∂U \;\text{is the enthalpy}.$$

Since $Q=0,$ we can rearrange the equation to: $∂U = -W$

We know that $W = PdV,$ using the combined gas law ($PV=nRT$) we can rearrange this to:
$$W = \frac{nRT}{V} dV.$$

We know that $∂U = nCvdT,$ where $n$ is the number of moles of gas and $C_v$ is the heat capacity at constant volume.

Therefore, $$nC_vdT = -\frac{nRT}{V} dV$$

$n$ cancels to give: $$\frac{dT}{T} = \left(\frac{R}{C_v}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{dV}{V}\right)$$

We know that $R = C_p-C_v$ (where $C_p$ is the heat capacity at constant pressure)

Therefore, $$R= \frac{(C_p-C_v)}{C_v} = \frac{C_p}{C_v}-1$$

$$\frac{C_p}{C_v} =\gamma,\;\text{the heat capacity ratio}.$$

Since $$\begin{equation}\frac{R}{C_v} = γ-1, \\ \frac{dT}{T} = -(γ-1)\frac{dV}{V}\end{equation}$$

Integrating both sides yields:

$$\begin{equation}\int_{T_0}^{T}\frac{dT}{T} =  -(γ-1)\int_{V_0}^{V}\frac{dV}{V} \\ \implies \ln\left(\frac{T}{T_0}\right)= \ln{\left(\left(\frac{V}{V_0}\right) ^{-(\gamma-1)}\right)}\\ \implies\frac{T}{T_0}=\left(\frac{V}{V_0}\right)^{-(\gamma-1)} \end{equation}.$$

Here $V_0$ and $T_0$ represent the initial temperature and volume. Since $V > V_0,$ $\dfrac{V}{V_0}$ is greater than $1.$ However, $γ$ is greater than $1.$ This means that $1-γ$ is negative. Anything greater than $1$ to a negative power is less than $1$ but greater than zero.
This means that $\dfrac{T}{T_0}$ is less than $1$ but greater than zero. As a result, we can conclude that the initial temperature was greater than the final temperature.

## Hot and cold reservoirs, and the efficiency of a Carnot engine:

The efficiency of a Carnot engine is $\left(1 - \dfrac{T_c}{T_h}\right).$
$T_c$ is the cold reservoir, while $T_h$ is the hot reservoir. Since $T_c$ can never be $0$ Kelvin due to the Third Law of Thermodynamics, the efficiency can never be $100\%.$ This the temperature of the gas before the adiabatic expansion and $T_c$ is the temperature after, so $\dfrac{T_c}{T_h}$ is $\dfrac{T}{T_0},$ which we know from before is equal to $\left(\dfrac{V}{V_0}\right)^{(1-γ)}.$ In this way, efficiency, volume and temperature can all be related.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Phys.SE. Don't forget to utilise the fact that our site supports $\LaTeX.$ I've formatted all your equations this time. Also, don't mention your name in the answer. You've the profile to do that.